# synchronizing 10 threads with atomic bool

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdatomic

I'm trying to use 10 threads and each one needs to print his number and the printing needs to be synchronized. I'm doing it as homework and I have to use atomic variables to do it (no locks).

Here what I tried so far:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
atomic<bool> turn = true;

void print(int i);

int main()
{
  vector<thread> threads;

  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
    threads.push_back(thread(print, i));
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    threads[i].join();
  }

  return 0;
}


void print(int i)
{
  bool f = true;
  for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
  {
    while((turn.compare_exchange_weak(f, false)) == false)
    { }
    cout << i << endl;
    turn = turn.exchange(true);
  }
}
```

output example:

```
24 

9143 
541 

2 
8
```

expected output:

```
2
4
9
1
4
3
1
5 
4
10
8
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: the threads print isn't synchronized

Comment: what do you mean by "synchronised", please show a [mre] with the actual output of your program and the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 bugs in your use of `atomic`.

When compare_exchange_weak fails it stores the current value in the first parameter. If you want to keep trying the same value you need to set it back to the original value:

```
while ((turn.compare_exchange_weak(f, false)) == false)
{
  f = true;
}
```

The second issue is that `exchange` returns the currently stored value so:

```
turn = turn.exchange(true);
```

Sets the value of turn back to false, you need just:

```
turn.exchange(true);
```

Or even just:

```
turn = true;
```

Synchronisation isn't actually necessary in this case as `std::cout` will do the synchronisation for you, single output operations wont overlap so you can just change your `print` function to the following and it will just work:

```
void print(int i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        cout << std::to_string(i) + "\n";
    }
}
```

Atomics aren't the right approach to this problem, your code is incredibly slow. Mutexes would probably be quicker.